# Regular expression for special character

Tags: ruby, regex

Users on my website have the ability to enter resume information such as experience in a `textarea`.  The problem I am having is I am getting *unordered* list characters and characters such as  from the user pasting in resume information.  I would like to remove such instances.

I'm not sure how to match for an unordered list character and a .

Please advise.

Update

What I have so far:

```
 before_save :strip_skills_experience

 def strip_skills_experience
  self.skills = skills.gsub(/[\u2022]/, '')
#self.experience = experience.gsub(/[\u2022]/, '')
end
```

Using the following:

```
 self.skills = skills.gsub(/[^\w\s\.&!,;:\(\)\$\-%\*\+"'\\\[\]\{\}\?<>`~\|=\^]/, '')
```

Comment: `unordered list character` What is this? Can you give some example?

Comment: • test
 • test
 • test

Comment: @Brian: The bullet is `\u2022`. The other character is from Private Use Area (it means it is free for anyone to define characters), Plane 0 (http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/private_use_area.html). There are 2 other Private Use Areas in Plane 15 and 16.

Comment: Andrew, I only set up a before filter and a basic gsub testing replacement. I wasn't sure what to call these characters to start trying to match.

Comment: nhahtdh, is there a way to prevent these?

Comment: Is there any reason that you're not using a whitelist for allowed characters?

Comment: fardjad, I'm not sure how to do that. I is there a NOT operator? Like remove every but NOT [a-z1-9], etc

Comment: @Brian Yes there is, suppose you want to remove every non alphanumeric characters from your input, the regex to match them would be: `[^A-Za-z0-9]` (`^` is NOT operator.) You can simply replace the matched characters with `""`.

Comment: Good deal. I tried it out and seems to be working. I just need to build the list of acceptable characters. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll turn my comment into an answer then.

Comment: Striping characters that don't fit into the ASCII range will nicely remove characters from words and names that have accented characters, causing them to be misspelled. Imagine how happy your users will be when they can't enter their names, city and street, or previous companies worked for. This will rule out every language that uses non ASCII characters, ensuring that users will go to another site.

Instead, take time to read about [transcoding of characters](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_string). Read all the articles there to really understand what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a whitelist to allow certain characters in user input:

Suppose you want to remove every non alphanumeric characters, the regular expression to match them would be: `[^A-Za-z0-9]`. Now you can simply replace the matched characters with `""`.

Comment: This will nicely strip characters from words and names that have accented characters, causing them to be misspelled, and rule out every language that uses non ASCII characters, ensuring that users will go to another site.

Comment: What the Tin Man said is right, try [^[:alnum:]] instead to include unicode alphabeticals. (btw you could have simplified yours to \W)